# Why doesn't my socket.io project on Heroku sleep?

Tags: heroku, socket.io, sleep

It's a **Node.js** app serving a **React** app. I'm using free dynos so the app should sleep after not receiving any request, but it seems to be always on. I checked the billing on **Heroku** and it's consuming a significant amount of hours.

I would be fine waiting for the app to load up, but it won't sleep. Perhaps it has something to do with **socket.io** constantly pinging the server while no client is connected?

I only find topics on how to prevent sleeping, totally opposite of my intention. I also have another **socket.io** app on **Heroku**, but that one does sleep like expected.

Edit: The app logs tell that there are two socket connections made **at the same time every 30 minutes**, my app seems to be pinged by a pinger. How to stop unknown pinger?

Comment: I'd start with this note from the docs: "

Occasionally, monitoring services such as Pingdom or New Relic monitoring can prevent a web dyno from sleeping. Run `heroku logs -t` to view your app’s logs to see if this is the case and turn off these services if it is happening."

Comment: Actually the logs show strange connections every 30min, my app is probably being pinged by a pinger.

Answer (score 0):

My **Heroku** app was actually being pinged by a pinger. I freed the app from the pinger by changing the app name. Isn't it bad that anyone can add an app to a pinger and the publisher has to change the app name?

Comment: Well, how would you prevent such a thing? It's at least nice to know someone likes your app enough to want it to stay online, heh.